# AWS cdk python, which IAM role for a glue crawler with a daily trigger?

Tags: python-3.6, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-glue, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a `glue crawler` for an s3. Unfortunately I cant manage to find an appropriate IAM role that allows the crawler to run. The permissions I need are just to read/write to S3, and logs:PutLogsEvent, but somehow I am not getting it right.
Here is my code, it can be deployed but the `crawler` does not have permissions to run.

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_events as events,
    aws_lambda as lambda_,
    aws_events_targets as targets,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_glue as glue,
    core
)

class MyStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # what should I put in the role exactly?
        glue_role = iam.Role(
            self, 'Role__arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole',
            assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal('glue.amazonaws.com'),
        )
        glue_trigger = glue.CfnTrigger(self, "glue-daily-trigger",
            name = "etl-trigger",
            schedule = "cron(5 * * * ? *)", # every hour at X.05, every day
            type="SCHEDULED",
            actions=[
                {
                    "jobName": "glue_crawler-daily"
                }
            ],
            start_on_creation=True
        )
        crawler_name = 'crawler_units_data'
        glue_crawler = glue.CfnCrawler(
            self, crawler_name,
            name=crawler_name,
            database_name='data_science',
            role=glue_role.role_arn,#'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole',
            targets={"s3Targets": [{"path": "s3://random_s3/units/"}]},
        )
        glue_trigger.add_depends_on(glue_crawler)
```

I tried several things and translating code from javascript examples [like this one](https://gist.github.com/cadocx/ddbef58c2d3a3fa92be4ddd15721fcd0) but the methods being called from javascript do not map 100% with python.

This role (created from the GUI) works correctly and has 2 policies.

1. Policy to read and write from s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::random_s3/units*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. AWSGlueServicePolicy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:*",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue-*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*aws-glue-*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::crawler-public*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:/aws-glue/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "aws-glue-service-resource"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you try glue_role = iam.Role(
            scope=self,
            id="Role__id",
            assumed_by=aws_iam.ServicePrincipal("glue.amazonaws.com"),

). ?  Also update your question with IAM policy details attached to the role if it is still not working properly

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy , 1. What should I try exactly? you suggested exactly the same code I posted. 2) what do you mean with attach policy details to the role? something like `glue_role.add_to_policy..`?

Comment: can you change 'glue_role' to id="Role__id" id here mean the full ARN of the Glue role that you have used. The IAM Policies which are attached to the Glue role that you have

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I updated the question. The crawler gets created but i dont manage to assign it the right IAM role. As the GUI suggests ```This role must provide permissions similar to the AWS managed policy, AWSGlueServiceRole, plus access to your data stores.```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, I needed to pass the name and policy in a different way

```
    glue_role = iam.Role(
        self, 'glue_role_id2323',
        role_name = 'Rolename',
        assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal('glue.amazonaws.com'),
        managed_policies=[iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name('service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole')]
    )
```